# Android: how to determine the number of items in a row in GridView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-gridview

I draw a matrix by GridView. In case 4x4, it works ok (per row contains 4 items) with default value. Problem happens when drawing 5x5, only 4 items on per row.

[image]

My idea: resize item width = (screen width) / number items per row. Its OK? if its right, someone could give me code to do that (sorry, I am new in Android)

OR, could anyone give me other idea, or code example for this in all cases (5x5, 6x6, etc)?

--- My code ---
MainLayout.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id = "@+id/container" 
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center" 
android:orientation="vertical" >

<GridView
    android:id="@+id/gridView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="0dp"
    android:layout_margin="0dp"
    android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
    android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:columnWidth="60dp"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"    
    android:gravity="center" >

</GridView>
```

ImageAdapter

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private Context mContext;

public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
    mContext = c;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    //return 0;
    return mThumbIds.length;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ImageView imageView;
    if (convertView == null) {  // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
        imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(85, 85));
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        imageView.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
    } else {
        imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
    }

    imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
    return imageView;
}

// references to our images
private Integer[] mThumbIds = {
        //green code: BBE833
        R.drawable.green_cell, R.drawable.green_cell,
        R.drawable.green_cell, R.drawable.green_cell,
        R.drawable.green_cell, R.drawable.green_cell,
        R.drawable.green_cell, R.drawable.green_cell,
        R.drawable.green_cell, R.drawable.green_cell,
        R.drawable.green_cell, R.drawable.green_cell,
        R.drawable.green_cell, R.drawable.green_cell,
        R.drawable.green_cell, R.drawable.green_cell,
        R.drawable.green_cell, R.drawable.green_cell,
        R.drawable.green_cell, R.drawable.green_cell,
        R.drawable.green_cell, R.drawable.green_cell,
        R.drawable.green_cell, R.drawable.green_cell,
        R.drawable.green_cell
};
```

MyActivity.java

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_quiz);
    SecureRandom securerandom = new SecureRandom();
    int randomLoop = 15;

    final GridView gridview = (GridView)findViewById(R.id.gridView1);
    final ImageAdapter imageAdapter = new ImageAdapter(this);
    for (int i = 0; i < randomLoop; i++) {
        int position = securerandom.nextInt(25);
        imageAdapter.updateCell(position);
    }
    gridview.setAdapter(imageAdapter);
    gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
            //Toast.makeText(QuizActivity.this, "" + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            imageAdapter.updateCell(position);
            //a = 11;
            gridview.setAdapter(imageAdapter);
        }
    });
```

p/s: I just hard code for size 5x5
Thanks.

Comment: Paste your layout code too.

Comment: Check : https://github.com/jess-anders/two-way-gridview

Comment: @Haresh: could you teach me how can use two-way-gridview? Thanks

Comment: please download zip from github and get sample code from.

Comment: @Haresh: ok. But, I read the description, maybe it does not serve for this cases

Comment: No one help me! My question is not clear?

Answer (score 0):

To get the number of columns in a `GridView`, use the method `getNumColumns()`

For example:

```
gridview.getNumColumns();
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridView.html#getNumColumns()

Comment: Maybe, you misunderstand my problem. I dont want to get number of columns in a GridView. I want to how to "determine the number of items in a row in GridView"

Comment: What do you define as an 'item'? A GridView usually represents one item per row, per column. So a 5x5 grid is 5 rows by 5 columns, containing 25 items.

Comment: I just follow this google guide to draw the matrix by GridView http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html. For item definition, you can read this guide.

Comment: OK, so it's a standard grid view, and my answer still stands. Each row contains getNumColumns() number of items. I'm asking you what are you calling an item? What is it to you? What are you trying to determine? From what you're describin, you want to know how many grid view items are inflated per row. That number is equal to the number of columns in your grid.

Comment: An item is a circle. "That number is equal to the number of columns in your grid" yes, I know that. but, as I told, an item's dimension not enough for 5 in a row (I set GridView numColumns=auto-fit instead 5 because this value is changed at runtime). If I set numColumns=5, items are mixed (item2 cover a part of item1, item3 cover a part of item2,...). That why I want to resize it to fit in a row for all cases.

Answer (score 0):

To get the number of items in a GridLayout use the `getChildCount()` method